# Allegro error in DevC++

Tags: c, compiler-construction, allegro

I am running the latest DevC++ 5.5.3 and I need to use the Allegro 5.0.4 so I downloaded it from devpaks and install it common way. But when I want to run the project with allegro the compiler show me error "allegro.h: No such file or directory". I was looking for the answer but I haven't found the relevant one. And what more I have to use DevC++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro.h>
int main(void)
{
    allegro_init();
    allegro_message("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

Linker is set to `-lalleg`

Comment: You need to tell the compiler where to find the Allegro header files. This is done with the `-I` (as in capital i) option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allegro 5 is not backward compatible with Allegro 4. It is a brand new library made by the same people.

Your code snippet is for Allegro 4.

The equivalent is:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>

int main(void)
{
    al_init();
    // al_init_native_dialog_addon(); // Introduced in 5.0.9
    al_show_native_message_box( /* fill in params */ );

    return 0;
}
```

You would need to link against the main Allegro library along with the native dialogs library.